# Please correct my Query

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
Select empno,sum(cast(substring(othours,0,3)as float)) as
Hour,sum(cast(substring(othours,4,5)as float)) as Minutes from tmstrans 
group by empno,othours
```

it is showing data like following

- 1 , 10
- 1 , 30
- 2 , 10
- 2 , 30

i need data like following

- 1 , 40
- 2 , 40

please help

Comment: remove `othours` from the `group` by clause

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to `SUM` both Hour and Minutes columns, you've to remove the `othours` column from the `GROUP BY` clause. Test it like this:

```
SELECT empno,
       SUM(CAST(SUBSTRING(othours,0,3) AS float)) AS Hour,
       SUM(CAST(SUBSTRING(othours,4,5) AS float)) AS Minutes
FROM tmstrans 
GROUP BY empno
```